# Подвинуть блок вниз

Tags: css

Посредине есть 3 колонки (к блока), под ними один большой, при наполнении из одной колонок она расширяется по вертикали и налазит на нижний блок. Вопрос: как опустить нижний блок относительно одной из колонок?

```
.wrapper{
    width:990px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
    background-color:silver;
}
.menu{ // меню колонок
    width:99%;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:200px;
    max-height:400px;

}
.pravka{ // нижний блок
    position:relative;
    width:99%;
    margin:2px auto;
    height:600px;
background-color:yellow;
}
.block_menu1,.block_menu2,.block_menu3{
    position:relative;
    width:19.3%;
    margin:4px 2px;
    min-height:20px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid lime;
    background-color:green;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for .pravka {clear:both;}
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало)